# Android: issue creating directory

Tags: java, android, file, sd-card

I'm trying to create a directory inside the gallery folder (to store videos and photos nothing more), I tried this code:

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/dirname");
 dir.makedirs() ;
```

The problem is when I browse the SD card files and folders using the file manager everything is OK and the file does exist, but when I open my gallery there is no dir called dirname. What is the problem?

Thanks :-)

Comment: is dirname contains any media image files?

Comment: no its empty for now @Pavan

Comment: just add one image and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my function that take a bitmap and save it in a directory ...

```
 public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    if (createDirIfNotExists("TestApp")) {
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "TestApp/TestSC" + date_value + "_" + time_value + ".png";
        File imagePath = new File(filePath);
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            hideLoadingDialog();
            showAlert(getString(R.string.successfullySavedPic));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            hideLoadingDialog();
            showAlert(getString(R.string.problemOccured));
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            hideLoadingDialog();
            showAlert(getString(R.string.problemOccured));
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    } else {
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Pictures/TestSC" + date_value + "_" + time_value + ".png";
        File imagePath = new File(filePath);
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            hideLoadingDialog();
            showAlert(getString(R.string.successfullySavedPic));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            hideLoadingDialog();
            showAlert(getString(R.string.successfullySavedPic));
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            hideLoadingDialog();
            showAlert(getString(R.string.successfullySavedPic));
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


}
```

createDirIfNotExist() :

```
public static boolean createDirIfNotExists(String path) {
    boolean ret = true;

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "Problem creating Image folder");
            ret = false;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getAbsolutePath()`:

```
String filePathDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath()
            + "/"
            + appNameFolder
            + "/"
            + innerFolder;
File fileDir = new File(filePathDir);
if (!fileDir.exists())
    fileDir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523658/how-to-create-application-specific-folder-in-android-gallery)